# Proving $A\times(B\cup C)=(A\times B)\cup(A\times C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove that $A\times(B\cup C)=(A\times B)\cup(A\times C)$

**My Try:**

$(x,y)\in A\times(B\cup C) $

$x\in A$ and $y\in(B\cup C)$

$(x\in A$ and $y\in B)$ or $(x\in A$ and $y\in C)$

$(x,y)\in A\times B$ or $(x,y)\in A\times C$

$(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cup(A\times C)$

$(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cup(A\times C)$

So, I proved $A\times(B\cap C)\subset(A\times B)\cup(A\times C)$

**My question: Do I also need to prove** $(A\times B)\cup(A\times C)\subset A\times(B\cap C)?$

Comment: Of course you do

Comment: Yes you do. To prove equality you have to prove $x\in A \iff x\in B$, which means $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B \wedge x\in B \Rightarrow x\in A$

Answer (score 4):

Just write $\iff$ arrows between the statements.

Comment: Where and what is it meant to write $\iff$ ?

Comment: @user982787 You need to emphasize each of your lines is true iff the other is, so you can just place $\iff$ at the beginning of each line (except the first one).

Comment: If I place $\iff$, then I need not prove $(A×B)∪(A×C)⊂A×(B∩C)$ this right?

Comment: @user982787 When as in a proof like this all inferences can be made validly in both directions, you get both proof directions for the price of one write-up.

Comment: Just add "... and vice versa, as all implications are biconditional."